# Netflix style image continuous carousels with mouse-over with Bootstrap support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can someone suggest any Twitter Bootstrap supported jquery plugins that can provide Netflix style continuously scrolling image carousel with mouse-over?
I have already explored the carousel provided in Bootstrap JS library but it requires click of button and is not continuously scrolling, but instead just scrolls the full set of images under an item.

Any info of such cool plugins is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Though not bootstrap/jquery based, but even better (pure css!), I came across [one](https://codepen.io/joshhunt/pen/LVQZRa) which is a decent place to start at and extend

**HTML:**

```
<div class="contain">

  <h1>Pure CSS Netflix Video Carousel</h1>

  <p>
    Inspired by  <a href="https://twitter.com/Eli_White">Eli White's</a> article <a href="http://eng.wealthfront.com/2015/06/implementing-netflix-redesign.html">Performant CSS Animations: Netflix Case Study</a>, his <a href="https://codepen.io/TheSavior/pen/LVeYBp">example pen</a>, and <a href="http://matthewjamestaylor.com/">Matt Taylor's</a> <a href="https://codepen.io/mattjamestaylor/pen/dodYPr">CSS-only version.</a>
  </p>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="row__inner">

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-1.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-2.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-3.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-4.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-5.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-6.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-7.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-8.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-9.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-10.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-11.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-12.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-13.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-14.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-15.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-16.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-17.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-18.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tile">
        <div class="tile__media">
          <img class="tile__img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/70390/show-19.jpg" alt=""  />
        </div>
        <div class="tile__details">
          <div class="tile__title">
            Top Gear
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body,
html {
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background: #0e0f11;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1,
p {
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
a:link,
a:hover,
a:active,
a:visited {
  -webkit-transition: color 150ms;
  transition: color 150ms;
  color: #95a5a6;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #7f8c8d;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.contain {
  width: 100%;
}
.row {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
.row__inner {
  -webkit-transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms transform;
  transition: 450ms transform, 450ms -webkit-transform;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 70.3125px 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.tile {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 140.625px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 450ms all;
  transition: 450ms all;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
          transform-origin: center left;
}
.tile__img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 140.625px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}
.tile__details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(0,0,0,0.9)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  -webkit-transition: 450ms opacity;
  transition: 450ms opacity;
}
.tile__details:after,
.tile__details:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: #000;
}
.tile__details:after {
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #ecf0f1;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
.tile__details:before {
  content: '▶';
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.tile:hover .tile__details {
  opacity: 1;
}
.tile__title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row__inner:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-62.5px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-62.5px, 0, 0);
}
.row__inner:hover .tile {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.row__inner:hover .tile:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 1;
}
.tile:hover ~ .tile {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(125px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(125px, 0, 0);
}
```